# How to import Netbeans project Maven EAR (EJB + WEB) to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web, ejb, ear, netbeans-8

My question is simple : How to import Netbeans Maven project EAR (EJB + WEB) to Eclipse ?

Comment: Open your Eclipse IDE, on the top left corner select: *File* > *Import* > *Maven* > *Existing Maven Projects*, press *Next* and select the root directory of your project.